# purrring with NULL listcolumns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- rownames_to_column(mtcars,var = "car")
mtcars$make <- map_chr(mtcars$car,~strsplit(.x," ")[[1]][1])

mt2 <- mtcars %>% select(1:8,make) %>% nest(-make,.key = "l")
mt4<-mt2[1:5,]
mt4[c(1,5),"l"] <- list(list(NULL))
```

Now, I´d like to run the following function for each make of car:

```
fun_mt <- function(df){
      a <- df %>%
        filter(cyl<8) %>%
        arrange(mpg) %>% 
        slice(1) %>% 
        select(mpg,disp)
      return(a)  
    } 
mt4 %>% mutate(newdf=map(l,~possibly(fun_mt(.x),otherwise = "NA"))) %>% unnest(newdf)
```

However, the NULL columns refuse to evaluate due to

```
Error: no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

I also tried using the safely and possibly approach, but still I get an error msg:

```
Error: Don't know how to convert NULL into a function
```

Any good solutions to this?

Comment: Why are you using `NULL` at all? What is `NULL` supposed to indicate? Can you use `NA` instead?

Comment: @gregor I end up with NULL in the ensuing dataset after using left_joins on two different listcolumns. I dont think i can coerce a left_join into NA instead of <NULL>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `NULL` gets passed into the function `fun_mt()`. You wanted to catch this with `possibly()`. But `possibly()` is a function operator, i.e. you pass it a function and it returns a function. So, your call should have been

```
~ possibly(fun_mt, otherwise = "NA"))(.x)
```

But this doesn't yet work with `unnest()`. Instead of a character `"NA"` (a bad idea anyway, rather use a proper `NA`) you would have to default to a data frame:

```
~ possibly(fun_mt, otherwise = data.frame(mpg = NA, disp = NA))(.x)
```

Comment: @Maximillian Girlich - Thx. But do you have any idea why I dont get a listcol back when I do ` m<-mt4[1:5,] %>% mutate(newdf=map_df(l,~.x %>% 
                            {ifelse(is.null(.x), yes = as_tibble(NULL), no = fun_mt(.x))}))`